# Racket Recursive Square Function

Tags: list, recursion, racket

I am trying to write a function in racket that takes in a list of numbers and outputs a list containing the square of those numbers. I am trying to not use the map implementation and instead solve the problem recursively. However, the code I have now is outputting the same list that was the input. The code I have is as follows:

```
  (define (my-square lst)
         (cond (cons? lst)
               (append  (* (first lst) (first lst))  (my-square (rest lst)))))
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

The base case is wrong (it should ask for the empty list), and `cons` should be used for recursively building a list (instead of `append`). Also, you have a couple of errors regarding parentheses, and the last condition in a `cond` should be specified using `else`. This is the standard template for building an output list:

```
(define (my-square lst)
  (cond ((empty? lst)
         empty)
        (else
         (cons (* (first lst) (first lst))
               (my-square (rest lst))))))
```

That's fine for a solution written from scratch, but the idiomatic way to solve this problem in Racket would be to use a higher-order function, such as [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) - so we don't reinvent the wheel:

```
(define (my-square lst)
  (map (lambda (x) (* x x)) lst))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(my-square '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(1 4 9 16 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

`append` should be `cons`, and you should handle the case when `lst` is empty. Finally, `cond` conditions should be wrapped in parentheses:

```
(define (my-square lst)
  (cond ((cons? lst) (cons (* (first lst) (first lst)) (my-square (rest lst))))
        (#t '())))
```